# Numpy reshape behaves differently on square matrices

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following data:

```py
weights = [
    np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 2, 3])]),
    np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 2, 3])]),
    np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 2, 3])]),
    np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 2, 3])]),
    np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 2, 3])]),
]

len_models = len(weights)
len_layers = len(weights[0])
```

If I try to reshape the data as such: `x = np.reshape(weights, (len_layers, len_models))`, I'm getting an error:

> cannot reshape array of size 30 into shape (2,5)

However, if the weights have the following values:

```py
weights = [
    np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])]),
    np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])]),
    np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])]),
    np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])]),
    np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])]),
]
```

The reshape operation works.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the shapes as `np.arrays`:

```py
weights = np.array([
    np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 2, 3])]),
    np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 2, 3])]),
    np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 2, 3])]),
    np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 2, 3])]),
    np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 2, 3])]),
])
weights.shape # (5,2,3)
weights.dtype # dtype('int32')
```

Why reshaping to just `(5,2)` is not possible should be obvious now.

The second case:

```py
weights = np.array([
    np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])]),
    np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])]),
    np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])]),
    np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])]),
    np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])]),
])
weights.shape # (5,2)
weights.dtype # dtype('O')
```

The 3rd dimension is of different length (3 and 4) which creates an array of objects that treats the 3rd dimension as "one" blob. This is also indicated by a warning:

> VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
> np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])])